# Dialogflow change surface from webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to send a response from my webhook to trigger the process to change to another surface, but Actions on Google always throws:

> MalformedResponse 'final_response' must be set.

And that it's not very helpful.

This is the JSON I am returning:

```
{
    "payload": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": true,
            "conversationToken": "{\"data\":{}}",
            "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}",
            "expectedInputs": [
                {
                    "inputPrompt": {
                        "richInitialPrompt": {
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "simpleResponse": {
                                        "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "possibleIntents": [
                        {
                            "intent": "actions.intent.NEW_SURFACE",
                            "inputValueData": {
                                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.NewSurfaceValueSpec",
                                "capabilities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "context": "Sure, I have some sample images for you.",
                                "notificationTitle": "Sample Images"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

On Dialogflow I have setup 2 intents; one intent that returns the json specified here, and another intent with the event actions_intent_NEW_SURFACE, so I know what the user responded to the question to change surface.

I have been reading these sites:

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/WebhookResponse

https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json#dialogflow-response-body

[Action On Google, webhook response with actions.intent.NEW_SURFACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896991/action-on-google-webhook-response-with-actions-intent-new-surface) (This seems like the same problem has I have, but the OP didn't write the response.)

But none of them throw me some light on this matter.

Comment: Suggestion: try and use standalone AoG NodeJS client - https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs
OR 
AoG client with Dialogflow Fulfillment Client - https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs 
These will help you in coding and it is easy to use features like Surface Switching, Permissions, RichUI through these Clients.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I am with you, using NodeJS is much easier than a webhook implementation, because all of the documentation is for Node. But the webhook decision comes from the necessity to use other tools from the framework I am using.

Comment: Which version are you using of Dialogflow and AoG?

Comment: Dialogflow v2.
AoG I think there is only one?

Comment: Looks like the documentation in https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations is old and that doesn't work. I have tried to send the NEW_SURFACE intent as a systemIntent and that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to send a full Action SDK body as part of your Dialogflow response. While the `payload.google` portion of the JSON contains objects that are *similar* to the Action SDK response, there are some differences. You can see https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json#dialogflow-response-body for a full example of what the response should be when using a helper, but I think your response needs to be something like

```
{
    "payload": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": true,
            "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}",
            "richResponse": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "systemIntent": {
                "intent": "actions.intent.NEW_SURFACE",
                "inputValueData": {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.NewSurfaceValueSpec",
                    "capabilities": [
                        "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
                    ],
                    "context": "Sure, I have some sample images for you.",
                    "notificationTitle": "Sample Images"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep I figure it out too. The misunderstanding for me was that here: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations the JSON has a format, and then on the link you have have other. And on that link they don't say that NEW_SURFACE is an available option.
PS: Can you change capabilities to: "capabilities": ["actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"] and I set this as a valid response?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question in the comment. If that is related to this question, please ask it in the question. If it is a new question, please post a new one.